# Can I hide my Lamba formulas in Excel, so that it isn't visible in Name Manager

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create an excel file with lots of Lamba functions and share it to others. By I don't want to expose my lambda function to users of that excel file. For any other name in name manager (named ranges), I can hide it in Name Manager using vba, but I am not able to hide a lambda function.

Comment: The only way I can see you being able to do this, is if you place the lambda functions in a separate worksheet which is hidden and password protected. I am not sure how dynamic this approach would be and controlling inputs and outputs could be difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assertion is not correct: *For any other name in name manager (named ranges), I can hide it in Name Manager using vba, but I am not able to hide a lambda function.*

You can hide a named Lambda function with VBA. Follow these steps:

1. Create new excel sheet
2. Go to Name Manager and create a new name with a reference to a lambda function. In the below example, I used a named range of `myDoubleFunction` and gave it a formula of `=LAMBDA(aNumber,aNumber*2)`

[image]

3. Confirm the name works by entering it in a cell

[image]

4. Add and run the following macro to the workbook

:

```
Sub hideLambda()
Const nameToHide = "myDoubleFunction"
Dim n As Name

    For Each n In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If InStr(1, n.Name, nameToHide, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            n.Visible = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```

Your named range will not be displayed in your list of named ranges, nor will it auto-populate if you enter the name in a cell. The calculation will continue to work though as shown below:
[image]

It should be emphasized that this is hardly secure and shouldn't be considered a secure method of protecting users from seeing your formulas. The process for unhiding it is equally simple, even if you protect some of the workbook.

Comment: Never new that. BTW, didn't you mean `If StrComp(n.Name, nameToHide, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 no... `instr` is checking for a matching a name position. A `0` result would be if no match within the name.